# PHP creating dynamic variables looping through an array. Is there a way to loop through the dynamic varibales?

Tags: php, loops, variables, dynamic

I'm using this code to create dynamic variable for a loop through an array.

```
$var = [];

  foreach( $res as $obj ){
      $values=$obj->values;
   //   echo "<tr>";   
      foreach( $values as $k => $o ){
        $var['var'.$k] = $o->value;
         //echo $o->value[$k];
          
      } 
    //  echo "</tr>";      
  }
  extract($var);

echo $var0 . $var1 . $var2. $var3. $var4. $var5. $var6. $var7;
```

There are 2 sets of results in the array I'm only getting one in the dynamic variables. Is there a way to loop through the dynamic variables?

Output:

```
United StatesADP, Work Smart from the StartNYPMI Document Solutions, Inc.Corninghttp://www.pmi-ny.comSeptember 241000InfoseminarThis is a testlikwid2@hotmail.comLink to partner event
```

Output should be:

```
Germany
ADP, ECM Intro
PMI Document Solutions, Inc.
Munich
http://www.pmi-ny.com
October 24
1200
Webinar
this is a test
bob@hotmail.com
Link to partner event

United States
ADP, Work Smart from the Start
NY
PMI Document Solutions, Inc.
Corning
http://www.pmi-ny.com
September 24
1000
Infoseminar
This is a test
likwid2@hotmail.com
Link to partner event
```

Ultimately I would like to build a table where I can take the variables and move the order around and put a couple variables in one cell and use them as links. IE $var0 = Germany and United States.

Comment: In general, when I see variable names like var1 var2 var3 etc it’s a pretty good indication that the logic is flawed. These names suggest that you really should be using an array, although I don’t comprehend what you’re wanting to accomplish because a simple variable holds only one thing. Perhaps if you showed a small sample of data and expected results we could help more. BTW, there are variable variables if this is what you’re looking for https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: You are right. I am over thinking and making it too complicated. Arrays are the way to go.